# express middleware validation

Tags: express, middleware

I am performing some validation in express 4 routes.  The validation is in a use and is performed on a post; I don't understand how to get the post to not fire if the validation fails.

```
exports.setRoutes = function setRoutes(router) {
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var parseJson = bodyParser.json();

    router.use(routeLocation, parseJson, function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.method === 'POST') {
            var err = // do some validation;
            IF ERR EXISTS, DON'T FIRE POST BELOW
         }
    }

    router.post('/',parseJson, function(req,res) {
      // insert row into database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to not fire the post, since it is a signal received by the server and can not be undone. But you can prevent a bad POST from doing anything on your system.

Here is how we handle validation during post calls:

```
function runValidationFunction(req,res){
    //do your validation here
}

 router.post('/',runValidationFunction,parseJson, function(req,res) {
      // insert row into database
 }
```

This way your validation function gets run before your logic. Hope that helps